# How to configure graphite to track multiple server

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, graphite

We are currently using graphite inside a server farm and we want to track our java apps for all our farm but for each server too.

So far it seem that only the global one is working and even if in each apps server we created a different agent with the name of the server. (they are all different)

we send the graphite data to a EC2 instance (external to were our instance are located) where graphite is running but the EC2 instance seem too only have the agent of the last loaded server.

Can I be that since our request are going through a proxy graphite consider that they are from the same source even if we give them different agent name ?

How can we prevent from logging all metric under one agent ?

The only solution I see right now is to put graphite withing the same network the farm is but that would take week since we have to wait for another group to give us acces and configure other box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why it wasn't working it's because we were using dns instead of the ip. 
Use the ip of your instance and it shouldn't be a problem.